# Specifying a SEND (sharing) intent filter for a Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter, android-sharing

I am trying to filter and handle intents with `android.intent.action.SEND` actions in one of my `Service`s. I wrote the following in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<service 
    android:name=".app.ScreamerService"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
    </intent-filter>                                                                    
</service>
```

Now, the problem is that I don't see my application in the list of "share via" options when, for instance, trying to share a web page from the browser or a contact from the list of contacts. If, however, I move the intent filters to the main `<activity>` tag (instead of the `<service>`), my application name and icon **do** appear on the list of "share via" options.

What am I doing wrong here? Can't a `SEND` action be directed to a Service?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am trying to filter and handle intents with android.intent.action.SEND actions in one of my services.

`ACTION_SEND` is an activity action and therefore cannot be picked up by services or broadcast receivers.

> Now, the problem is that I don't see my application in the list of "share via" options when, for instance,

That is because it is not an activity.

> Can't a SEND action be directed to a Service?

Things that appear in a chooser (e.g.,. for `ACTION_SEND`) must be activities. Your activity is welcome to communicate with a service, though.

Answer (score 1):

This should work but:

Try with a broadcast receiver first to get the intent and launch your service.

if that doesn't work:

Use a dummy activity with no layout. (make the theme translucent and call finish right after you handle the intent).

Also your mime type means that you are handling every single file type. is that what you need? i think you should make it more precise in the selection. you will get negative feedback if someone tries to use it with a type you don't support. my suggestion is to test types and add them one by one as you are confident you can handle them.