# App does not show up in Android share dialog for text

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to have an app show up in the share dialog for text. The app itself has no activity, just theoretically receives a text from a share, and does stuff with it. But when I install it, it does in fact show up in the app list in settings, but when I open any app that can share text, it doesn't show up in the list of apps

This is my Manifest file

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service android:name="com.example.app.Share">
        <intent-filter android:label="Share with my app">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here is the class (most of it is just template code from the Android developer guides

```java
package com.example.app;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Share extends IntentService {
    public Share() {
        super("Downloader");
    }
    public Share(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get intent, action and MIME type
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
            } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
                handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
            }
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
                handleSendMultipleImages(intent); // Handle multiple images being sent
            }
        } else {
            // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
        }
    }

    void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
        String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (sharedText != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sharedText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Update UI to reflect text being shared
        }
    }

    void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
        Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (imageUri != null) {
            // Update UI to reflect image being shared
        }
    }

    void handleSendMultipleImages(Intent intent) {
        ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (imageUris != null) {
            // Update UI to reflect multiple images being shared
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: The opening `application` tag is missing the closing sign `>` at the end (11th line)

Comment: @kasptom it was there in the actual file, guess I messed up while copying and pasting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying a SEND (sharing) intent filter for a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084840/specifying-a-send-sharing-intent-filter-for-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs listed under [Sharing simple data](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/index.html) I think handling [android.intent.action.SEND](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) is not possible with the direct use of a service.
The examples show the way of handling the intent inside the activity (the IntentService does not have the `onCreate()` method).

Also, `android.intent.action.SEND` does not appear in the hints when you want to set the `<acion android:name="...">` inside the service's `<intent-filter>` section (`ctrl + space` in Android Studio when you type in the name)

However, if you use the Activity instead of the IntentService you can find the hint (cause we are now under the activity's `<intent-filter>` section) and your application's name is visible in the share list.

**EDIT:**

> or at least something to make the app not open up

you can try the approach proposed in [DArkO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11085260/4880379):

> Use a dummy activity with no layout. (make the theme translucent and call finish right after you handle the intent)

Comment: So how can I make it an activity, or whatever I need to get it to show up, without there being an actual activity, or at least something to make the app not open up

Comment: I set the intent to a blank activity I made and it now shows up under the share list, but as I said, is there any way to at least not make the app open?